# Why a call to a user-defined String() for user-defined type throws "not enough arguments in call to BitFlag.String"?

Tags: go

I list the code from the book "Programming in Go".
I test it but it didn't work well.

```
error: "not enough arguments in call to BitFlag.String"
```

Goplayground Code: http://play.golang.org/p/FG23LdS_xK

```
type BitFlag int

func main() {
    flag := Active | Send
    BitFlag.String();
}

func (flag BitFlag) String() string {
   ...
}
```

Why do I see this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call String on an instance of `BitFlag` (here '`flag`'), not on the `BitFlag` type itself.

```
flag := Active | Send
fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(int(flag)))
fmt.Println(flag.String())
```

See this [<kbd>play.golang.org</kbd> example](http://play.golang.org/p/vCCFYb2z3P).

Output:

```
3
3(Active|Send)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and the optimization of my questions, learning.

Comment: @Albert No problem. Welcome on Stack Overflow. Don't forget the tour (http://stackoverflow.com/tour), or the help center like http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.